# Fitting a sine data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to fit the data attached below with a function of the form `-a*sin(b*x + c)` (or maybe could be also with `-a*sin(2*x)`) with `a b c` as the values to determine. I used `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, but it does not work so well (as you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9UcN.png)).  How can I improve this?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

data = open('pruebaData.dat', 'r')
lines = data.readlines()[1:]
x = []                
y = []

for line in lines:
pos = line.split()
if pos != []:
    x.append(float(pos[0]))
    y.append(float(pos[1]))

z = []
for k in range(len(x)):
   z.append(np.deg2rad(x[k]))

valX = np.asarray(z)
valY = np.asarray(y)

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def fitFunc(X,a,b,c):
   return (- a*np.sin(b*X + c))

fig = plt.figure(2, figsize = (10,8))

init_vals = [1,1,1]    
best_vals, covar = curve_fit(fitFunc, valX, valY, p0=init_vals,  maxfev = 15000)
line1 = plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color = 'k', ms = 6)
fig2 = plt.plot(x,fitFunc(valX,best_vals[0],best_vals[1], best_vals[2]), '-
', color = 'k', lw = 1)
print('PARAMETERS:',best_vals)

plt.ylabel(r'DATA Y',fontsize=30)
plt.xlabel(r'DATA X',fontsize=30)
plt.xlim(min(x),max(x))
locs,labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(locs, fontsize = 20)
locs,labels = plt.yticks()
plt.yticks(locs, fontsize = 20)
plt.savefig('prueba.png', dpi = 500)
```

[PruebaData.dat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B48poInSsRzGYjN1Z3ZfNDFTd0E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Fitting periodic functions is always tricky. Change the initial value of the frequency `b` to match the expected frequency better.

Comment: Your data do not look like a sinusoidal. Maybe a superposition of two Gaussians would work better. Or, if you know that your data were supposed to be sinusoidal - then your experiment is bad.

Comment: can you fix your indentation please?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, i *don't* see that this is a bad fit ... for a sine.  Are you expecting a two-peaked function?  If so, you'll need to "explain" that to the `fit` function by supplying an error function that matches your feeling of fitness.  Yes, you can fit the center part of this data much better with 2.5 cycles of a sine wave, but the left and right extremities of the wave would turn upward again, while the data trend distinctly down.  This mismatch is what gives you the half-cycle wave.

You might experiment with error functions, such as sqrt(error) instead of error^2.  A bi-modal Gaussian distribution would fit this much better.  If you truly need sinusoidal, consider a Fourier transform, which will give you a combination (sum) of both sine waves -- and a lot of smaller-amplitude waves to account for the noise.